# Getting Master Occurrence for Private Appointments

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm having trouble finding out how to get the master occurrence for a series of private appointments using the Exchange Web Service Managed API for C#.

When I retrieve the list of appointments using FindAppointments on the ExchangeService, I manage to get the occurrences within the search criteria. However, when I then try to get the recurring master appointment using Appointment.BindToRecurringMaster where the id is the id of the private occurrence, I get the error "The specified object was not found in the store., Item not found."

Is there any other way for me to retrieve the master occurrence for a private occurrence?

In my example below, I'm authenticating using a service account which as the Reviewer permissions on the target mailbox calendar.

```
var exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("service.user@organization.com", "password", "domain");

const string email = "other.user@organization.com";

// The following successfully retrieve all appointments including the private occurrence.
var appointments = exchangeService.FindAppointments(
    new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(email)),
    new CalendarView(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)));

const string id = "AAMkA..."; // Id of the private occurrence.
// The following fails saying "The specified object was not found in the store., Item not found."
var appointment = Appointment.BindToRecurringMaster(exchangeService, id);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464784/how-to-get-the-recurring-master-of-all-recurring-series-that-have-one-or-more-oc possible similar like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your describing is the expected behaviour for private Items if you haven't been delegated access to view private Items via the Delegate Operation. So you would need to either give the Service Account Delegate rights on the Mailbox using the Delegate operations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641959(v=exchg.150).aspx and set ViewPrivateItems to true. Or give the Service Account FullAccess to the Mailbox or use EWS Impersonation.