# EWS: BindToRecurringMaster is slow, just need the recurring master Id

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

We are trying to list appointments for a given period for a given calendar.

For each of those appointments, if the appointment is recurring, we want to know the `Id` of the master appointment.

The issue is that the following code:

```
ItemId masterId = Appointment.BindToRecurringMaster(
    Service, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly));
```

Is extremely slow, because it makes an EWS call for every recurring appointment.

Is there a faster way to get **JUST** the `Id` of the recurring master appointment?

Comment: Seems that EWS has no schema compatible to Appointment, that contains a property for linking back to the recurrence master. Sad, but looks true. You can look deeper with EWS Editor: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ewseditor

Comment: I believe you can use FindAppointments(). This will allow you to sepcify a date range for a Calendar View. Once the appointments comeback the AppointmentType for recurring master will be RecurringMaster

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx

This StackOverflow shows how to use the FindAppointments as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464784/how-to-get-the-recurring-master-of-all-recurring-series-that-have-one-or-more-oc

Comment: Ok forget my previous comment. I was able to do a bit more research and according to Microsoft Documentation:
"Note that recurring master calendar items aren't returned in a call to FindAppointments. If you want to retrieve recurring masters, or you want a more general approach to retrieving calendar items, you need to use ExchangeService.FindItems. "
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643672(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: @Matt what a bummer.  If you wanna put that in an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do a bit more research and according to Microsoft Documentation:
"Note that recurring master calendar items aren't returned in a call to FindAppointments. If you want to retrieve recurring masters, or you want a more general approach to retrieving calendar items, you need to use ExchangeService.FindItems.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643672(v=exchg.150).aspx